# ThreeJS: update camera FOV

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to update a camera field of vision without creating a new camera.  I've been able to do this with position by using the code below:

```
camera.position.set()
```

I'd like to set this up in a similar way with the fov:

```
camera.fov.set()
```

This isn't working in the script.  Can anyone else suggest a quick method?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to recompute the projectionMatrix:

```
camera.fov = 20;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

This may be prettified in the future though...